# Description for a stopped containers

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I added a rule into the rules.yml in order to get an alert whenever a container stops.
In order to get an alert for each stopped container with the suffix "dev-23", I used this rule:

```
- alert: ContainerKilled
    expr:  absent(container_start_time_seconds{name=~".*dev-23"})
    for: 0m
    labels:
      severity: 'critical'
    annotations:
      summary: 'Container killed (instance {{ $labels.instance }})'
      description: 'A container has disappeared\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}'
```

This indeed works, and I get an alert whenever a container that ends with "dev-23" stops. However, the summary and description of the receieved alert do not tell me what is the name of the stopped container.
In the alert I get this description:

```
description = A container has disappeared\n VALUE = 1\n LABELS: map[]
summary = Container killed (instance )
```

What should I use in order to get the exact name of the stopped container?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the metrics created with the `absent()` function does not have any labels and its value is always `1` (if the queried metric is not present)

You can leave it like that, without any label, if you just want to check if there is NO container running at all, without any details about its previous state and that is enough information to detect the issue.

Or you can use the `UP` metric, that has the labels, but potentially disappers, e.g. when you have a dynamic service discovery.

In general it a good practice to have an alert on `UP{...}==0` and on `absent({...})`

Comment: Thanks. Actually it appears that if i use the exact contianer name, and use this rule:  ContainerKilled
    expr:  absent(container_start_time_seconds{name="be-dev-23"})
    for: 15m
    labels:
      severity: 'warning'
    annotations:
      summary: 'Container killed'
      description: 'A container{{ $labels.name }} has disappeared'   it works OK and i get the container name. It is only when i use a regexp such as "name=~".*dev-23" that the notification fails

Comment: In addition the "up" metric does not seem to monitor containers as they are not listed as a Prometheus target... it is the cadvisor which is a Prmetheus target. So unless I am mistaken "up" cannot be used for alerting on containers

Comment: you didnt mention that the metrics are not provided by your containers but the cadvisor (only) in your question. In general it might be a good idea that the containers expose some metrics and probetheus can scrape them, then you have the UP metrics

Comment: Thanks. Is there some place that explains how can my containers expose metrics?

Comment: that depends on your containers. when they are exposing metrics, they do it via http and the default path is `/metrics` what metrics they expose (and if) is dependent on what runs in your contrainers.